# css @media print not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I am trying to change style of printed document using css (@media print) and have defined a simple style to change the heading fontsize while printing. However the style for print media is not changed at all. Could anyone tell where I went wrong? Thanks! 
Here's what I did

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testmediacss.aspx.cs" Inherits="PrintDemo1.testmediacss" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" >
   @media print { body {font: 50pt Arial;} h1 {font-size: 138pt;} h2 {font-size: 15pt; color: #000;} }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function CallPrint(strid){
            var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
           var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=1000,top=1000,width=1000,height=500,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
           WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
            WinPrint.document.close();
            WinPrint.focus();
            WinPrint.print();
            WinPrint.close();
       }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div  id="divprint">
        <p>hello this is the part to be printed in the printer.</p>

        <h1>hello world</h1>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="CallPrint('divprint');" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: though you have a typo in window.open i.e. letf(it shd be left), but still it works for me. even on IE 8

Comment: Your CSS is valid. I just tested it.

Comment: @ScottBartell though it is valid it still donesn't show the desired result.Don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I have always used both media print and media screen when defining css.

```
@media print
{
  h1 {font-size: 138pt;}
}
@media screen
{
 h1 { font size: 95pt;}
}
```

It will show up on the screen as 95 point text, but print as the 138 point text.

Comment: There's no need to specify screen because it's the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=1000,top=1000,width=1000,height=500,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
```

Not `letf`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, at least in Chrome, that CSS just gets ignored...after pressing `Ctrl + R` like 20 times, or even better clearing your cache, it will finally work...